# How to find the value stored in a particular index of a multiset in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Assume I have a multiset as {1,3,5,7,9}. I want to find what is the 3rd element in this multiset using C++. How can I do that without using a loop?

Comment: `*(++ ++ms.begin())`

Comment: If you need indexed access to a container, `std::multiset` is probably the wrong choice for the container type. `std::vector` and `std::deque` provide constant-time indexed access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez"

Answer (score 3):

A multiset is normally implemented as a tree, so you have to traverse through it node by node to find a particular node in order. In other words, regardless of how you express it (loop or otherwise) it's going to take N operations to get to the N<sup>th</sup> item in the tree.

If your interest is purely in avoiding writing the loop, you can...disguise it by using something like:

```
auto p = mySet.begin();
std::advance(p, 2);
```

...but that will only hide the loop inside of `advance`, not really eliminate it. `std::next` will do the job as well, but (again) just hides the loop, doesn't eliminate it.

Although `std::set`/`std::multiset` don't provide it, if you need to do this a lot, there is specialized variant of a tree that supports finding the N<sup>th</sup> element in O(log N) time (with O(N) space overhead).

Along with the data normally in the tree, in each node, you store the number of elements in that node's sub-trees. You start by finding the index of the root by subtracting the size of its left sub-tree from its own size. If the index you're looking for is greater than that, you descend to the right. If it's less, you descend to the left (and if its equal, you've found the node you're looking for).

As you descend, you need to keep a running count of your location. You've already figured out the index of the root, so you keep that in the running count. Then when you descend into a node, if you're descending to the right you add the 1 + size of new node's left sub-tree. If you're descending to the left, you subtract 1 + size of right sub-tree.

To maintain the counts, as you're inserting anytime you descend through a node you increment its count (and as you're deleting, you decrement its count--but only after verifying that the value to be deleted was present).

If you want to search for more details, this is normally called an "order statistic tree".

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a2b5bc7aeb2cc8f3

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -5):

this one should point to the 2th element of the array

> int a[] = {1,3,5,7,9}; int *p = a; std::cout << *(++a) <

Comment: But I want to work for any index.