# C++ multiset, return key at position?

Tags: c++, multiset

The [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/) states that the `multiset` data object has property `ordered`. Therefore, for a `multiset` named, e.g. `ms`, it should be unambiguous to retrieve the set element at a given position `i` such that `0 <= i < ms.size()`. I tried accessing these elements as `ms[i]`. However, the language complains that `multiset` does not support subscripts.

What syntax do I use to access element `i` in a `multiset`?

Comment: Very similar (but closed) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219142/how-to-find-the-value-stored-in-a-particular-index-of-a-multiset-in-c).

Comment: A set (or multiset) is usually stored as tree. Hence, access via key is quite efficient. Access via index is not. (A tree does not support random access to nodes like e.g. an array does.) Of course, there are clever combinations (trees with all nodes stored in an array) but that's not the case for `std::set` or `std::multiset` (to have other advantages).

Comment: If you want to get the ith element you'd have to iterate from ms.begin() to ms.begin() + i. No random access since it's a tree.

Comment: @Scheff thank you for the clarification. I guess I will have to be content with iterating through the container, or dumping it into a `vector` after creation.

Comment: For a `std::multiset<T>`, you could create a `std::vector<std::multiset<T>::iterator>`. This would be such a combination like mentioned above. However, if the multiset is subject of frequent modifications, the updating of the vector is probably very expensive.